# Change the sender's email address using Gmail SMTP on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, smtp, gmail, google-workspace, wpforms

Online quote entries are sent to my email, and the "from" section says the email was sent from my email, not the customer's.
I switched my hosting to Cloudways and started using Google Workspace to increase security and ease of use. The previous hosting had cPanel. The current one is self-hosting, which works differently than cPanel.

I'm currently using WPForms along with WP Mail SMTP. I set up Google Workspace/ Gmail using OAuth to authenticate the account.

When a customer enters their details such as name, phone, email, etc, the notification/email I get to my email says it was sent from me. I want it to display the customer's name and email instead of my email.

I tried a different plug-in to set up workspace/Gmail SMTP.
I tried changing email notifications from WPForms.